# Vector 3d Plotting with New Mathematica Version

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, physics, vector

Hi Used to use the old version of Mathematica back in 2020. Now the new version is updated and I am trying to run the old code in the new version. My vector plots are very different. I wonder what I should do to get a better image. Here is the code. The image attached is based on the old version. In the recent version, the image is very different. I want to have a vector 3d plot the image shown as desired new output.

```
{X = 1; Y = 1;
R = 2 X/8;
fmZ = 0.2;
\[Theta][x_, y_] := \[Pi]/2 - 
   2 ArcTan[Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/R^2)]]; (*Polar angle*)
t = 1; (*Skyrmion of the first kind \[Rule] t=0; Skyrmion of the \
second kind \[Rule] t=1 *)


(*cos and sin of azimuthal angle*)
\[Phi][x_, y_ ] := ArcTan[x, y] - Pi/2; "Dn";

g6 = VectorPlot3D[{Cos[\[Phi][x, y ]] Sin[\[Theta][x, y]], 
    Sin[\[Phi][x, y ]] Sin[\[Theta][x, y]], 
    Cos[\[Theta][x, y]]}, {x, -X, X}, {y, - Y, Y}, {z, fmZ/2, 
    fmZ/2 + 0.01}, VectorScale -> 0.05, VectorPoints -> 25, 
   VectorStyle -> {Blue, "Arrow3D"}, 
   VectorColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, n}, 
     ColorData["TemperatureMap"][
      Exp[-40 ((x - 0.5)^2 + (y - .5)^2)]]], Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.03}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 0.4], 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style[Framed[Subscript[D, n]], 16, Blue, Bold, 
     Background -> Lighter[Yellow]]];
Show[g6]}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `fmZ`isn't defined!

Comment: fmZ I defined and also attached an image of the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

```
X = 1; Y = 1;
R = 2 X/8;
fmZ = 0.2;
θ[x_, y_] := π/2 - 
  2 ArcTan[Exp[-((x^2 + y^2)/
        R^2)]];(*Polar angle*)t = 1;(*Skyrmion of the first kind\
\[Rule]t=0;Skyrmion of the second kind\[Rule]t=1*)(*cos and sin of \
azimuthal angle*)ϕ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y] -  π/2;

SliceVectorPlot3D[
 {Cos[ϕ[x, y]] Sin[θ[x, y]], 
  Sin[ϕ[x, y]] Sin[θ[x, y]], Cos[θ[x, y]]}
 , z == fmZ/2
 , {x, -X, X}, {y, -Y, Y}, {z, -1, 1}
 , PlotStyle -> None
 , BoundaryStyle -> None
 , VectorPoints -> {25, 25}
 , VectorScaling -> None
 , VectorSizes -> 0.6
 , VectorColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, n}, 
   ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Exp[-40 ((x - 0.5)^2 + (y - .5)^2)]]]
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> False
 , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 0.4]
 , PlotLabel -> Style[Framed[Subscript[D, n]]
   , 16, Blue, Bold, Background -> Lighter[Yellow]]
 , ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using 13.2. That's why it's showing issues. How about the one image called desired output?

Comment: In place of "TemperatureMap", try "NeonColors" and add `, Lighting -> "Accent"`. Or substitute the color map, if you have one.

Comment: I want to try VectorColorFunction -> (Blend[{Green, Red}, #3] &), just to match the other figures mentioned in this post (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289204/3d-vector-wrap-of-half-sphere/289206?noredirect=1#comment720038_289206), but getting everything blue.

Comment: Use: `VectorColorFunction -> (Blend[{Lighter@Green, Red}, 
    Exp[-40 ((#1 - 0.5)^2 + (#2 - 0.5)^2)]] &)`